# CSS inline-block acting as float

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a site that uses a nice grid structure using [inline-block instead of floats](http://justifygrid.com).

In a nutshell, my grid works like so [(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9njm2oxa/1/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- .grid -->
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0;
}
.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.half {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Now if we take a look at this page: http://bit.ly/1AJM9Qt, it works as it should like in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9njm2oxa/1/).

However, when I use the exact same method on this page: http://bit.ly/1zezIIx, each `div` acts as if it has a `float` applied instead of `inline-block`. Each `div` should distribute equally.

I really cannot see any difference in the two pages and cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can i ask why your avoiding using floats?

Comment: exactly how you want?

Comment: I'm no longer using PHP counters to apply a `.last` class. It also means I cut down on using clearings and it tidies up my media queries.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1zezIIx has no whitespace between the `div`s so they can't be justified to fit the parent width. Add a space between the `div`s and they should act as you expect them to.

Comment: Of course! My PHP was being echoed in a series of strings which was creating no whitespace. Thank you @HiddenHobbes, you've saved the day! Please set as your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: No problem, it's something that has often caught me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bit.ly/1zezIIx has no whitespace between the `div`s so they can't be justified to fit the parent width. If you add a space between the `div`s and they should act as you expect them to.

### Example without whitespace (content is not justified)

```css
.grid {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0;
}
.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.half {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    background: red;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"><div class="half"><p>Here's some content</p></div><div class="half"><p>Here's some content</p></div><div class="half"><p>Here's some content</p></div><div class="half"><p>Here's some content</p></div></div>
```

### Example with whitespace (content is justified)

```css
.grid {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0;
}
.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.half {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    background: red;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <p>Here's some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding margin to each of the grid items to separate them?

```
.half:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin-right: 4%;
}
```

Comment: The method I've used means you don't need to use margins. As you can see from the JSFiddle, each div is equally distributed.